# Matlab Distributed Computing Excel Read MDCE Error

Tags: windows, matlab, windows-services, distributed

I have a distributed computing network set up and as a part of the distributed run I need to open EXCEL through xlsread etc.

The problem is that the MCDE windows service is not able to do this resulting in this error:

"Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'C:...\Book2003.xls'. There are several possible reasons:

- The file name or path does not exist.
- The file is being used by another program.
- The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.”

The solution is:

Check if these folders exist: C:\Temp & C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop .

If not, manually create them.

Comment: Is this an answer to a question?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to have it available for anyone who had the same issue.  EDIT: this is more of  a note for the future so it will be searchable

Comment: OK, that's very nice of you. But in that case, you can post it as a question, answer it yourself then accept your answer.